# Cahrt.js Guage no muestra datos de variable php

Tags: php, javascript, chart.js

Buen día, al mostrar este gauge Chart y le paso un valor de una variable php por javascript no lo grafica, lo raro es que si lo imprime en pantalla con un echo, osea que el valor de la variable php se almacena en la variable javascript que estoy creando pero no lo grafica y si pongo un valor directo en la variable js este si lo grafica, podrían ayudarme?

> //este es el valor a pasar para idEmp (variable de

```
  javascript el cual si imprime pero no grafica)
    <?php

    $idEmpleado= 99;
     ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
```

> ```
>        <!--variable de php a javascript-->
> ```

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
              var idEmp = "<?php echo $idEmpleado; ?>";
            document.write("idEmpleado = " + idEmp);



            </script>


            var hand = chart.hands.push(new am4charts.ClockHand());

              chart.setTimeout(valPregGraf, 2000);

>       //aquí se pasan los datos a la gráfica en la variable de java idEmp es el dato que necesito herede del echo de php.     
                  function valPregGraf() {
                      hand.showValue(idEmp, 1000, am4core.ease.cubicOut);
                      chart.setTimeout(valPregGraf, 2000);

                }

                });
```

Comparto el link del código completo para que lo chequen, gracias.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zvB8g0ni-csYKn9p0VeBfBsFxJ3yjdIm

Comment: No entiendo nada, estructura mejor tu pregunta con código legible. Para que no te pase eso, te recomiendo utilizar un evento `onload` y ahí ejecutar la función de tu chart. Reitero, necesitas re-formular tu pregunta.

Comment: listo ya lo modifique

Comment: Para comprobar variables y ver como llegan puedes usar `console.log('Mi variable: ' + variable);` y podrás ver la variable en la consola del navegador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en tipo de dato.

Si pones ...

```
  hand.value = parseInt(idEmp);
```

Con **parseInt()** se soluciona el problema. Transforma la variable a INT.

Más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt